# Create a xml file using jsp coding and store in local disk folder

Tags: jsp

Can I create a xml file using jsp coding and store it into a local disk with the specified name we giving. 
The xml file structure like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<questions>
<question category="something"/>
</questions>
```

If is this possible please give coding for that.

Comment: not understand about storing it on local disk. If you want to output xml from jsp , just add <%@ page contentType="text/xml" %> in header , next put your xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,org.w3c.dom.*,javax.xml.parsers.*,javax.xml.transform.*, javax.xml.transform.dom.*,javax.xml.transform.stream.*"%>  
<%!
public void createXml(String graph) throws Exception{
try{
    String str="dinesh";
    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
    // questionset elements
    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("questionset");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);
    // question elements
    Element question = doc.createElement("question");
    rootElement.appendChild(question);
    // set attribute to question element
    Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("category");
    attr.setValue("graph");
    question.setAttributeNode(attr);
    // write the content into xml file        

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();

    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    transformer.transform(source, result);
    String xmlString = sw.toString();

    File file=new File("C:xml/"+str+".xml");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    bw.write(xmlString);
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.println(e);
}   
}
%>
<% 
String graph=request.getParameter("graph");
createXml(graph);
%>
```

save the above coding as any jsp page eg. new.jsp

Change the name of the file str="want u want" 
and also change the attribute `attr.setValue("want u want");`

U can also change the local disk folder where the file want to save